# Why does Edge not honour my PC's locale settings (specifically, date format)?

Tags: locale, microsoft-edge

My PC locale is set to en-IE. The locale short date format here is dd/mm/yyyy.

When I add an `<input type="date">` element to my webpages, Edge shows a placeholder value of mm/dd/yyyy. Given Edge should be more tightly integrated into Windows than any other browser, I'm scratching my head over this one.

Firefox displays the placeholder correctly without me touching anything. For Chrome, I do recall having to set my language preferences to use English (UK) by default some weeks ago, presumably because it doesn't have English (Ireland) as an option and so fell back to English (US) by default instead.

Is this a bug in Edge, or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://web.archive.org/web/20171210193252/https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7465343/) in Edge.

Answer (score 7):

The 2020 new version of Edge is based on Chrome coding so it does not take language setting from Windows 10 preferences. On Edge go to 3 dots on top right, click. Select Settings, Languages. Select Add Languages and select English UK from drop down list. Install and click on dots near language and set Use this language in Microsoft Edge. The date format will be dd/mm/yyyy after you restart. Ensure you select English UK and not the non-specific  "English" which Edge installs with or English US as both of these result in other date format.

Comment: This unfortunately means that if you have a different locale (e.g., Swedish) than English US or UK on Windows, you cannot display dates or currencies formatted in a Swedish format while still displaying the browser language in English.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to ... (three dots) / Settings / Languages and **remove your preferred language and then install it again** and make it as default and also set it on TOP. This seems to be bug in chromium-based browsers (same bug / workaround also works in google chrome)